# Deadlock in MS SQL Server on update of same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, dynamic-sql

I am getting too many issues with deadlock in my environment. Deadlock mainly happen when trying the upadate.  I have installed SentryOne to know what happens with deadlock.. We are having very complex system and getting lot of deadlocks on same table.

My transaction level is repeatable Read and I am getting cycle Deadlocks on the same table.
What are the steps i can take to avoid cyclic deadlocks.
How do we make sure cyclic deadlock doesn't occur in code.

Below is showing key lock on Reservations indexname="IX_Reservations_ReservationId_OrganizationId. I do have 18k records in the resut set and do indexing seemed to be applied. But showing index scan on ReservationOrgananization index. Do you think case statement is the cause of index scan. I do many selects with case condition inside the transaction that uses insert, update delete

[image]
[image]

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
[Extent1].[AdjustmentAmount] AS [AdjustmentAmount], 
[Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
[Extent1].[ReservationAdjustment_Reservation] AS [ReservationAdjustment_Reservation], 
[Extent1].[ReservationAdjustment_Promotion] AS [ReservationAdjustment_Promotion], 
[Extent1].[ReservationAdjustment_AdjustmentReason] AS [ReservationAdjustment_AdjustmentReason], 
[Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[ReservationProductId] AS [ReservationProductId]
FROM  [dbo].[ReservationAdjustments] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Reservations] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ReservationAdjustment_Reservation] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE 123 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[OrganizationId] = @p__linq__0) THEN [Extent2].[Id] END)

<deadlock>
<victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process23b4b08c8" />
</victim-list>
<process-list>
    <process id="process23b4b08c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 6:30675207:0 " waittime="3311" ownerId="55794405" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-02-20T16:41:15.963" XDES="0x2a4125770" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="1" kpid="102820" status="suspended" spid="94" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-02-20T16:41:16.403" lastbatchcompleted="2019-02-20T16:41:16.390" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.390" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="''"" ''" loginname="''"" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="55794405" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="234" stmtend="670" sqlhandle="0x0200000066d3ee34a3aa9027d9cf2157cf5cca17470f03dd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@0 decimal(18,2),@1 decimal(18,2),@2 decimal(18,2),@3 bit,@4 nvarchar(255),@5 datetimeoffset(7),@6 int,@7 binary(8))update [dbo].[P]
set [TotalPrice] = @0, [PassengerTaxAndFees] = @1, [AgentCommission] = @2, [SupplierChangeExists] = @3, [ModifiedBy] = @4, [Modified] = @5
where (([Id] = @6) and ([RowVersion] = @7))
select [RowVersion]
from [dbo].[P]
where @@ROWCOUNT &gt; 0 and [Id] = @6   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process294aedc28" taskpriority="0" logused="12548" waitresource="OBJECT: 6:30675207:0 " waittime="6588" ownerId="55792892" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-02-20T16:41:12.020" XDES="0x2c5e09770" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="2" kpid="49456" status="suspended" spid="80" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-02-20T16:41:13.127" lastbatchcompleted="2019-02-20T16:41:13.123" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.123" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="''"" ''" loginname="''"" isolationlevel="repeatable read (3)" xactid="55792892" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="1062" stmtend="5572" sqlhandle="0x02000000328db70a915f43baef23378214e51d7e0cacc8c50000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@0 datetime2(7),@1 datetime2(7),@2 int,@3 decimal(18,2),@4 bit,@5 decimal(18,2),@6 bit,@7 bit,@8 nvarchar(255),@9 int,@10 decimal(18,2),@11 nvarchar(255),@12 nvarchar(25),@13 nvarchar(max) ,@14 nvarchar(255),@15 decimal(18,2),@16 nvarchar(25),@17 datetime2(7),@18 nvarchar(max) ,@19 decimal(18,2),@20 bit,@21 int,@22 int,@23 bit,@24 bit,@25 bit,@26 bit,@27 bit,@28 bit,@29 nvarchar(25),@30 bit,@31 bit,@32 nvarchar(255),@33 datetimeoffset(7),@34 nvarchar(255),@35 datetimeoffset(7),@36 int,@37 int,@38 int,@39 int,@40 int,@41 int)insert [dbo].[P]([EndDate], [StartDate], [Quantity], [PriceEach], [TotalPrice], [Comments], [NetRate], [NetRateAmountDue], [NetAmountPaid], [NetAmountPaidDate], [NetRatePaidInFull], [CommissionPaidInFull], [Owner], [Organization], [Source], [SourceConfirmationNumber], [PassengerTaxAndFees], [PassengerTaxesAndFeesDescription], [Destination], [ProductType], [Description], [RateDe   </inputbuf>
    </process>
</process-list>
<resource-list>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="30675207" subresource="FULL" dbid="6" objectname="''.dbo.P" id="lock2ab07a480" mode="S" associatedObjectId="30675207">
    <owner-list>
        <owner id="process294aedc28" mode="S" />
        <owner id="process294aedc28" mode="IX" requestType="convert" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process23b4b08c8" mode="IX" requestType="convert" />
    </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
    <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="30675207" subresource="FULL" dbid="6" objectname=".dbo.''"" id="lock2ab07a480" mode="S" associatedObjectId="30675207">
    <owner-list>
        <owner id="process23b4b08c8" mode="S" />
        <owner id="process23b4b08c8" mode="IX" requestType="convert" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process294aedc28" mode="IX" requestType="convert" />
    </waiter-list>
    </objectlock>
</resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: can you show us the queries you are using for update?

Comment: exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[ReservationProducts]
set [SupplierChangeExists] = @0, [ModifiedBy] = @1, [Modified] = @2, [ReservationProduct_Product] = @3
where (([Id] = @4) and ([RowVersion] = @5))
select [RowVersion]
from [dbo].[ReservationProducts]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = @4',N'@0 bit,@1 nvarchar(255),@2 datetimeoffset(7),@3 int,@4 int,@5 binary(8)',@0=0,@1=N'TestUser',@2='2019-02-19 06:25:26.2694583 +00:00',@3=107,@4=65094,@5=0x0000000000114DB1

Comment: You should upload deadlock graph as xml and not as a picture

Comment: Why is it taking S locks on the whole table? What isolation level are you running at? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: I am not sure why it downvote. I am not sure of the locks

Comment: It was not my downvote, but the reason may be that deadlock graph as a picture is useless. You should post it as xml

Comment: @sepupic i have added the deadlock xml.

Comment: Not sure what is the downvote for should have explainded what is the issue and then downvote.

Comment: I saw your xml but had no time to examine it, and now it's no more available, how can it be? Can you please attach it again?

Comment: I upvoted your question, no idea why it was downloaded, on contrary, with deadlock graph it was complete, with all the necessary info

Comment: @sepupic i have attached it, only one table falling into deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I'm answering this on my phone. So no diagrams.

This is a synchronization issue.

A deadlock generally occurs when two or more processes want access to the same record, page, or table (depending on lock granularity and lock escalation) but in a different order, especially if explicit transactions are involved, and especially if the system is under heavy load.

Say process A, in a transaction, updates record 1, then tries to update record 2.

Meanwhile, process B, in a transaction, updates record 2, then tries to read or update record 1. A has changed the record, so B can't even read it until A's transaction commits or rolls back. Likewise, A can't read the record B has locked, and boom, deadlock.

"I knew that", you're saying to yourself.

Well, yeah, but what I'm getting at is the order of operations issue. You mentioned the system is highly complex, and that is a bit of a giveaway. It is a synchronization issue. Do you know if different code paths in the system are running the same or similar queries in a different order?

In a healthy system, if process A updates record 1, then updates record 2, and process B runs those same operations in the same order, the requests will queue up and run consecutively. B will wait for A to finish, presuming the timeout isn't exceeded.

This works because B will never obtain a lock on record 2 while A is still holding a lock on record 1, because B wants to start with record 1 just like A, and cannot get it until A releases it.

You may be dealing with table locks instead of record locks if you are updating large ranges of records or doing a lot of reads inside your transactions with your isolation level set to serializable, etc. The same general principles apply.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here:

1. Your table has no `indexes` at least those that can be used in some `select` that was executed in the same transaction but was not catched by the `deadlock graph`.
2. Your transactions use `repeatable read` isolation level.

When you use `repeatable read`, the `shared locks` acquired are held until the end of the `transaction`.

Before your sessions try to make `update` (session 1) and insert (session 2), they make some select that locked the whole table, it's not catched in inputbuffer but maybe you know what code was executed prior data modification.

Both sessions hold `S-lock` on entire table and want to `update`/'insert', so they need to convert `S-lock` into `IX` as some rows in this `table` will be updated/inserted and the `intent lock` should be placed on the table.

`IX` is incompatible with `S` so the first session waits for second session when it releases its `S-lock` on the `table`, but the second session cannot commit because it also cannot `insert` as it needs `IX` on the same table and it cannot be granted since the first session holds `S-lock`.

In order to fix this you should find the prior `select` and create `indexes` that will permit to lock only some rows, not entire `table`, or you should get rid of `repeatable read`.

You can reproduce this by yourself this way:

open 2 SSMS query windows and first make a select in `repeatable read` that will lock the whole table, I do it using `tablock`:

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin tran 

select count(*)
from dbo.t with (tablock);
```

At this point both sessions hold `S-lock` on a `table`.
Now return to the first window and try to make an update:

```
update dbo.t
set col = 'bbb'
where id = 10;
```

This query will be blocked as it needs IX that cannot be granted,
you can see `lock` situation using this code (maybe you should filter for your session ids, I make my test on dedicated server with no activity):

```
select resource_type,
       request_session_id,
       resource_associated_entity_id,
       request_mode,
       request_type,
       request_status
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where resource_type not in ('DATABASE', 'METADATA');
```

[image]

Now as soon as the second session tries the insert, deadlock occurs:

```
insert into dbo.t (id, col)
values(3, 'aaa');
```

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned  no index can be an issue. When i ran the profiler and when i try to save i found see some queries which are quite big and when i see estimation plan it was showing missing index impact 77% and asking to add the suggested index. Do you think this can be a cause? I also see multiple connection opening do you think multiple connection can impact on it.

Comment: The problem is not in different connections. You should find all the SELECT that you have in the same transaction with update, in the same transaction with insert. Only when I see those select I can suggest you indexes

Comment: I just modified post added select statement which is creating deadlock with Select and inserting

Comment: Are you sure that it's this SELECT that executes prior di update/insert? In your deadlock there is a table(view?) called P, and the SELECT posted has other tables: Reservations and ReservationAdjustments. I need a SELECT that completely locks dbo.P

Comment: We are interested in select that could block entire **dbo.P**, not Reservations and ReservationAdjustments, as it's dbo.P that is locked with S lock at the object level

Comment: A missing index is not going to create a deadlock. At best, adding the index will cause the operations in question to run faster, which means contentious resources will be released more quickly, which will reduce the likelihood of a deadlock simply because the likelihood of the resource being available at any given instant is higher. But the "fix" is a side-effect which doesn't address the underlying issue at all. The underlying issue is the order of operations.